# Bluetooth headphones don't work at all :(

Tags: release-hera, sound, bluetooth

Today I bought a cheap usb bluetooth adapter to use it with my bluetooth headphones, and I've tried to connect them and use them. When I try to connect them it either says `Unable to connect` or asks me for a pin (Which it shouldn't do) and no matter what I put on the input, it says connected just to get disconnected after 5 minutes, and in these 5 minutes the headphones don't appear in the sound settings. So it's either not connecting or I'm missing something :(

I'm using `elementary OS 5.1.4 Hera` with `Linux 4.15.0-101-generic`

I've tried several fixes and I'm truly using this as my last resort
Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a possibility the bluetooth adapter just isn't supported in your current kernel. I'd recommend upgrading with the ubuntu HWE, and then making sure the "linux-firmware" package is installed.

Run the following in a terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 linux-firmware
```

Then reboot and test if it works.

Comment: It seems like the problem has... Evolved? Now it maintains connected if I'm in the bluetooth window, but disconnects as soon as I close it, and the sound still does not come from the headphones

Comment: Can you tell me what the bluetooth adapter is called, and what headset it is as well? It could also just be bluetooth system being bugged. Have you tried connecting other bluetooth devices, maybe a phone?

Comment: I tried connnecting the Xiaomi redmi headphones, JBL headphones and Beats. I also changed the bluetooth dongle (The seller tried it and said that it worked for him ini Windows 7). Running lsusb from the terminal returns "Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)"

Comment: A few google searches tells me this dongle is rather problematic. You can look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208296/bluetoot-adapter-configuration-issue-id-0a120001 and see if any of the answers are helpful. :)

Comment: Hecc :'( Now I have another problem, the beats connected, buuut now the audio from the laptop sometimes work and sometimes doesn't. I paid 3$ for this dongle but it feels like I paid with my soul lol

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had a similar problem. (The Device showing connected but not appearing in the sound settings and *then disconnecting*(additional problem))

I referred to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1151329/elementary-os-bluetooth-not-working) and the solution `sudo apt-get install blueman` worked for me. Figured out that it might help you out.

Note to Mods: This is **not an answer** but I don't have enough reps to comment, hence you may add it as comment and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

On Elementary OS Hera 5.1.7 (based on 18.04.4) using kernel 5.8.0-39 (necessary for hardware compatibility reasons), I was able to resolve this issue by

1. installing pavucontrol and blueman
   and
2. editing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
   "MultiProfile=multiple" under "general"
   (see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#A2DP_not_working_with_PulseAudio)
   change "AutoEnable=false" (not sure if that did anything)

Before this, I couldn't connect to bluetooth audio sinks, period, unless I used bluetoothctl. At that point, it would only connect to the duplex low quality sink (HSP/HFP) and not A2DP (high audio quality).

Now it appears to be able to work well enough in either mode, with mode-switching on the fly, however, with consistent errors:

```
[  994.225669] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000085e83e50 submission failed (90)
[  994.225675] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[  994.238145] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[  994.238153] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[  994.238155] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[  994.238157] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
```